# react-native run-ios failing after recent updates

Tags: android, ios, react-native

This method worked 1 month ago.

running:

`react-native run-ios`

returns following error:

```
Scanning 557 folders for symlinks in /home/michal/WebstormProjects/ReactNativeSampleApp/sampleapp/node_modules (2ms)
Found Xcode project sampleapp.xcodeproj

spawnSync xcrun ENOENT
```

Comment: Have you tried `rm -rf node_modules`, `npm install` and `npm start -- --reset-cache` (from your the root of the project, wherever `package.json` is)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After revisiting this question this is now what I do when react-native fails to build a project on a virtual/real device.

- Clear derived data `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
- Clear watchman `watchman watch-del-all`
- Remove node modules `rm -rf node_modules`
- Clean npm cache `npm cache clean --force`
- Clean temp directory `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*`
- Clean ios build `product -> clean`

Make sure that all libraries are linked: `react-native link`

- Install modules `npm install`
- Run dev server `node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start -- --reset-cache` (preferably manually from console because xcode does not reset cache)
- Build the project `react-native run-ios`